# Cannot deploy production capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, capistrano3

I'm trying to deploy my application using capistrano I have pushed the code to GitHub, however, I get the following

```
ben@ben-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/pol-v2$ cap production deploy
Stage not set, please call something such as `cap production deploy`, where production is a stage you have defined.
```

Here is what I have in my Capfile

```
require "capistrano/setup"
require "capistrano/deploy"

require "capistrano/scm/git"
install_plugin Capistrano::SCM::Git

require "capistrano/rbenv"
require "capistrano/rails/assets"
require "capistrano/rails/migrations"
require "capistrano/passenger"

set :rbenv_type, :user
set :rbenv_ruby, '2.5.1'

Dir.glob("lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake").each { |r| import r }
```

Here is my `deploy.rb`

```
lock "~> 3.11.0"

set :application, "pol_v2"
set :repo_url, "REPO LINK"
set :deploy_to, "DEPLOY PATH"

append :linked_files, "config/database.yml"
append :linked_dirs, "log", "tmp/pids", "tmp/cache", "tmp/sockets", "public/system"

set :keep_releases, 3
```

`production.rb`

```
set :stage, :production
server "IP", user: "USER", roles: %w{app db web}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this line `set :stage, :production` should be `set :rails_env, :production`